# How do I use serializer validation in function-based view? Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to be able to update instances through GET requests.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(
        r'^classes/(?P<pk>\d+)/add_student/(?P<student_id>\d+)', 
        views.add_student
    ),
]
```

views.py

```
def add_student(request, pk, student_id):
    class_ = get_object_or_404(Class, id=pk)
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, id=student_id)
    class_.students.add(student)
    return redirect('class-detail', pk=pk)
```

models.py

```
class Class(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField('Student', related_name='classes')
    ...

class Student(models.Model):
    ...
```

serializer.py

```
class ClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        students = data['students']
        max_capacity = data['max_capacity']
        if len(students) > max_capacity:
            msg = 'This class is full'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
```

This would successfully add a student to the class, even if the class is full. How do I update like this, and have it validated
by the serializer before a student gets added?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def add_student(request, pk, student_id):
    class_ = get_object_or_404(Class, id=pk)

    # Change is here
    serializer = ClassSerializer(data=class_)
    serializer.is_valid(True)
    serialized_class_data = serializer.data

    student = get_object_or_404(Student, id=student_id)
    class_.students.add(student)
    return redirect('class-detail', pk=pk)
```

If you need to validate via serializer, you need to pass the data/instance to be validated using keyword argument `data` and should call `.is_valid()` method.

For more info, please do refer to the [official DRF doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

**UPDATE**
According to your update and your `views.py` , you can check the count without using a v`validate()` in `serializer`.

Change your `views.py` as below:

```
from django.db.models import Count


def add_student(request, pk, student_id):
    class_ = get_object_or_404(Class, id=pk)
    std_count = class_.students.aggregate(count=Count('id'))['count']
    if std_count > max_capacity:
        return HttpResponse("This class is full")
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, id=student_id)
    class_.students.add(student)
    return redirect('class-detail', pk=pk)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help. I tried this but the problem still remains, student gets added to class_.students even if it is full. I edited my question and added my validation code on serializer.py, please take a look.

Comment: @BillVergara Updated the answer

Comment: I really want to keep validations in serializer only, because that's what they say good practice is, but thank you very much for this!.

Comment: You can't validate a `class instance` using serializer. It could possible only with `dict` like objects

Answer (score 1):

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

serializer **validate()** method get called only if you call **is_valid()** method on the serializer object.

change your method like this

```
def add_student(request, pk, student_id):
    class_ = get_object_or_404(Class, id=pk)
    serializer = ClassSerializer(data=class_)

    if serializer.is_valid():  # add student
        student = get_object_or_404(Student, id=student_id)
        class_.students.add(student)
        return redirect('class-detail', pk=pk)

    else:
        errors = serializer.errors
        # handle errors
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help. I tried this but the problem still remains, student gets added to class_.students even if it is full. I also tried to add student first before calling is_valid() but it still gets added. I edited my question and added my validation code on serializer.py, please take a look.